# Multi processor compilation of VS2015 produces "not enough quota is available to process this command" when running cl.exe

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, jenkins, msbuild

We are running automated Jenkins builds on Amazon servers (Windows Server 2012 R2) for a few Visual Studio solutions. The bigger projects in them are configured with the `/MP`, use multi processor compilation, attempting to minimize build time.

We run `msbuild` with its `/m` flag as well.

Problem is that after a few minutes we get:

> TRACKER : error TRK0002: Failed to execute command: ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\CL.exe" @C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpd19a7e5e426f4ec7baa597ed75516fd4.rsp". Not enough quota is available to process this command.

This problem occurs only when running Jenkins agent. With Visual Studio IDE everything is fine. When running MSBuild from command prompt everything is fine as well.

Any idea why that happens and we can work around it?

Running

```
WMIC CPU Get DeviceID,NumberOfCores,NumberOfLogicalProcessors
got
DeviceID  NumberOfCores  NumberOfLogicalProcessors
CPU0      2              4
```

Maybe VS2015 does not detect the number of effective processors correctly and crosses some process boundary of spawning too many processes concurrently?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Amazon servers, what could go wrong.  You need to read "not enough quota" as "you need to pay us more money".

Answer (score 1):

The problem was a quota was defined in WinRM as denoted here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee309367(v=vs.85).aspx
We changed the value of MaxProcessesPerShell to be higher than the default of 25 and voila.

Answer (score 0):

The facile answer from technet to "create more virtual memory" is actually probably worth a bash.

Jenkins, at the time it launches MSBuild appears to use `Runtime.exec()` (checkout `Launcher.java` if you're having a look at their code).

This typically creates a new process, that, at least initially, has the same memory footprint as the launching process. So for a bit of time you're probably running twice as much memory as necessary for the build process.  So having some more virtual memory available at launch time may be enough to allow the new process to run long enough for the launching process to finish and free.

Here's Technet's *cough* useful description of the error message: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc958981.aspx

Comment: The servers in question have 8GB virtual memory which is more than enough. Monitoring the server memory footprint did not discover irregularities in that regard. It seems that the way Jenkins agent is running on those servers (via WinRM) is not liked by the quota king.